# View gets cut when orientation is in Landscape

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, orientation, xcode9

When developed the app in XCode8 it used to work fine, both in Portrait and Landscape modes.

Didn't change anything particular.

Now started to developed in Xcode9, Portrait works fine but any View in the App, if switched to Landscape it acts weird. Like in the images , view gets cut off

[image]

[image]

I use Autolayouts in Storyboard...

Is this happening because of new `safearea` feature?

EDIT: View Hierarchy added for Sign View

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post your view debug hierarchy?

Comment: @ReinierMelian added.

Comment: You are probably setting some `cornerRadius` incorrectly. I would look for all places in your source code where you set `cornerRadius`.

Comment: @robmayoff This happens in every single view though. I wonder if it happens because of Hero, https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you could provide a single small minimalistic Xcode project which shows the effect.

Comment: @u.gen Did you check whether you forgot to call base.ALifeCycleMethod() when implementing your own UITabBarController life cycle methods? Sometimes this leads to strange behaviors, for any subclass of the UIViewController.

Answer (score 3):

This can be due to some layer effect which are applying unintentionally on **UIViewControllerWrapperView**.
Please Check your UIViewControllerWrapperView layer properties or some layer effect on your **UINavigationController**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please update your xcode to 9.2 if you are using any version below that.

next turn on the storyboard feature called - "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" option inside "File inspector"

then remove and re-apply the viewController constraints.

hope it will work!

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by anything, wihout reviewing the code this cant be answered properly.

My suggestions are to check for a `layer` property added to any view in the hierarchy. The view may not have been updated properly in Landscape mode due to 
 the **new `autoLayout` property of `Xcode 9`.**

I have a feeling that it may have been caused by the "Hugin.ShadowView", if any shadow property added, please check the constraint of the view it is added to and rectify it as needed for `Xcode 9`.

If this doesn't help you you may share a short and simple project file and i'll have a look at it.

Comment: If I knew the reason, I would fix it and wouldn't open a bounty, so I don't think I can create a sample project and upload it

Comment: Well then i don't think its possible for me to proceed any further, Have a nice day @u.gen.